# Parsing XML data in Python, then creating a database with this information in SQL

Tags: python, xml, database, sqlite

I am a bit confused about the output I am getting in the command window after running my code.  I am have reviewed each section a few different times, and I am not sure what is going wrong.

Why is the dictionary count printing, but the rest of the print statements are not showing up?  I also checked the table in the SQLite file, and none of my data is in the tables, just headings.

Have I overlooked something?  There is no error showing up, but it is not giving the output or data in the tables, even with the insert, select, and fetchone statements.

Thank you in advance for your comments!

Here is what I have been playing around with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('trackdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.excutescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;

CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    genre_id  INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER
);
''')   

fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'Library.xml'

# <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
# <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
# <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print 'Dict count:', len(all)
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')

    if name is None or artist is None or album or genre is None : continue

    print name, artist, album, genre, count, rating, length

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id)
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( album, artist_id ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )

    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))  
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
        (title, album_id, genre_id, len, rating, count)
       VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''',
        ( name, album_id, genre_id, length, rating, count ) )

conn.commit()
```

Am I missing a SELECT statement?  I tried to apply a JOIN statement to have the desired table with the track, genre, album and artists names exposed, but I can not really figure how to incorporate it.  I was getting an error when I tried genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0] If anyone can give me some insight, I would be most grateful.

Here is the link to the XML data:

http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/tracks.zip

It basically shows dictionaries within dictionaries of the different key/value pairs for the track information.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I find four errors that need to be corrected to make this program run.

1. In the fifth line of code:

```
cur.excutescript('''
```

should be:

```
cur.executescript('''
```

2. In your `CREATE TABLE` for Track you need to add the `artist_id` column:

```
CREATE TABLE Track (
  id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
  title TEXT  UNIQUE,
  album_id  INTEGER,
  artist_id INTEGER,
  genre_id  INTEGER);
```

`artist_id` will also need to be added to your `INSERT OR REPLACE` statement for the Track table:

```
cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
    (title, album_id, artist_id, genre_id)
   VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)''',
    ( name, album_id, artist_id, genre_id) )
```

3. You have references to count, rating and length, but they aren't part of your tables, so you can remove those from your code. These are in your lookup statements, your print statement, and your `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO` for the Tracks table.

4. In this line:

```
if name is None or artist is None or album or genre is None : continue
```

You're missing `is None` after album:

```
if name is None or artist is None or album is None or genre is None: continue
```

With those changes, the code works, displays the info from the print statement, and builds your db correctly.

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe I missed those.  Sorry.  I have lost a lot of sleep lately.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following adjustment that does the following:

- Fixes your `if` line inside loop, even suggests a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) replacement commented out.
- Avoids the multiple `SELECT` statement fetches as it revises both the Album and Track table inserts with an `INSERT INTO...SELECT` using implicit joins (i.e., only `WHERE` clauses)
- Adds `conn.commit()` to each execute statement since the preceding append queries are needed for Album and Track table and must be committed to database beforehand and not at the end.

Updated Code

```
stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print 'Dict count:', len(all)
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    count = int(lookup(entry, 'Play Count'))          # NUMERIC CONVERSION
    rating = float(lookup(entry, 'Rating'))           # NUMERIC CONVERSION
    length = float(lookup(entry, 'Total Time'))       # NUMERIC CONVERSION
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')

    if (name is None) or (artist is None) or (album is None) or (genre is None) : continue
    #if (i for i in (name, artist, album, genre) if i is None) : continue

    print name, artist, album, genre, count, rating, length

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name)
                 VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )    
    conn.commit()

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id)
                   SELECT ? As title, Artist.artist_id
                   FROM Artist
                   WHERE Artist.name = ?''', 
                   ( album, artist ) )
    conn.commit()

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name)
                 VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    conn.commit()

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track (title, album_id, genre_id,
                                                 len, rating, count)
                   SELECT ? As name, Album.album_id, Genre.genre_id, 
                          ? As len, ? As rating, ? As count
                   FROM Album, Genre
                   WHERE Album.title = ? AND Genre.name = ?;''',
                   ( name, length, rating, count, album, genre ))  

    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback.  I can't believe I made these careless mistakes.  My concentration wasn't so good when I wrote this.  I must sleep now::-D